# OpenLayers MVT layers and setting a style

Tags: javascript, geospatial, openlayers

How do you style a feature on a feature in an MVT tile layer?

I tried a ton of stuff that work on geoJSON layers (like if I simply change to geoJSON) but the MVT equivalent doesn't which is no good because the geoJSON layer is 89MB and the MVT is 3MB.

Here's what I did:

```html
 var stySimple = new ol.style.Style({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
       color: 'transparent' //#ADD8E6'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
       color: '#880000',
       width: 1
      })
     });
     
     var styleClick = new ol.style.Style({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
       color: '#ADD8E6'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
       color: '#008800',
       width: 2
      })
     });
        
        
          var layer = 'aw:gis_hucs';
     var huclayer = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
      style: stySimple,
      source: new ol.source.VectorTile({


       tilePixelRatio: 1, // oversampling when > 1
       tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
        maxZoom: 19
       }),
       format: new ol.format.MVT({featureClass: ol.Feature}),
       url: 'http://geo.host.org:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/' + layer + '@EPSG%3A' + projection_epsg_no + '@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf'
      })
     });
        
         var map = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [
      huclayer
      ],
      view: new ol.View({
       center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-84.32470703125, 33.8799896240234]),
       zoom: 7
      })
     });
        
        
         hoverInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({
      condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove,
      layers: [huclayer], 
      style: styleClick /****** NO BUENO 1 */
     });
    
    map.on('click', function(e) {
       var features = [];
      
      map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
       features.push(feature);
      });
       
     features.forEach(function(cv)
      {
      cv.setStyle(styleClick); /****** NO BUENO 2 */
      }
     );
    });
     
    
     map.addInteraction(hoverInteraction);
     hoverInteraction.on('select', function(e) {
      
      
     
      if (e.deselected) e.deselected.forEach(function(cv) {
        cv.setStyle(null);
       });
      if (e.selected) e.selected.forEach(function(cv) {
        cv.setStyle(styleClick); /****** NO BUENO 3 */
       });
      console.log(e);
     });
```

I am pretty dejected, depressed and frustrated. How are you supposed to set the style on features on an MVT layer?

OL is 4.1.12
Geoserver is 2.11

I get a good representation of the layer I am trying to interact with but absolutely no dynamic styling on a feature by feature basis. I see no way that I can do it dynamically despite posts suggesting otherwise. There are also posts that suggest you can't set a style on a feature that is on an MVT layer but no documentation that references it. I don't get any errors, I have done quite a bit of simplifying my code above to make it easy to see but a jsfiddle would require a live MVT layer which I can't produce and don't know where one lives.

The selection interaction does give me a good list of active and inactive features. What's the point if you can't make it show what is selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ol.layer.VectorTile` does not listen for style changes on features, because it is optimized to work with sources that have `ol.render.Feature` features instead of `ol.Feature`. So whenever you change feature styles, you have to call `huclayer.changed()` to trigger a re-render with the updated styles.